# Spring AOP pointcut is not triggered as expected

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have two methods  with diferent pointcuts, one is executed, the other no, and I can`t see why.
I have many methds and classes defined on the packages that you can see below.
I am using spring-boot in my project.

Here is the code:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.arlr.common.business.service..*(..))", returning = "result")
    public void afterReturningCommon(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
        doSomething();
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.arlr.godzilla.service..*(..))", returning = "result")
    public void afterReturningMyProject(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Define _not working_. Provide an example method that works and one that doesn't. Show us your setup. In short, provide an MCVE.

Comment: I mean that afterReturningCommon(..) methd is executed but not the afterReturningMyProject(..) method and it must be executed becouse I have a many methods to scan in those packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observing the methods on the other scanned classes, they are protected methdos, so I change it to public to solve the problem.

Comment: Please either delete your question (my recommendation) or at least accept your own answer in order to close the question. I am going to edit your subject to at least reflect what you have actually asked here. "Looking for solution on execution of aspect pointcut" is not a meaningful title.